# how to use public ip in my private network

Tags: networking, network-shares

I'm trying to use public IP address in my private network.

In a short, how to set public IP, which is different to endpoint IP of my private network, to my server in my private network?

Is other network equipment is needed for setting?

My server environment is CentOS

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. How do you want to use it? Do you want to assign it directly to a host in your network or do you want to forward services (HTTP, etc.) from the public ip to a private ip?

Comment: @joeqwerty, i want to assign another public IP to my server on my private network

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to configure Port Forwarding or a DMZ on your router to forward traffic that arrives as your Public IP to the Private IP of your server. This would be configured on your router. Refer to your router's manual for details.

If you can't figure it out please edit your question with your router information and details as to what you are trying to accomplish (and I mean **details**, not something nebulous like your previous comments).